# Making resize-mini-windows buffer-local while locally let-bound

Tags: buffers, debugging

Upon striking C-x s (save-some-buffers) or C-x C-c,
it report errorsin mini-buffer

```
Making resize-mini-windows buffer-local while locally let-bound.
```

Search the above errors but return no helpful results.

How could solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs has some variables to configure when the debugger should be invoked. They all begin with `debug-...`. For your situation the variable `debug-on-message` could help.

Set it to the string of the message and trigger the error. This should open a backtrace, which should help you to find the problematic piece of code.

Comment: You mean debut-on-entry, there is not such a debug-on-message.

Comment: @Algebra No I mean the *variable*. `debug-on-entry` is a command.

Comment: @Algebra see [(elisp) Error Debugging](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html).